# Global Variables in Header file causing redefinition error c++

Tags: c++, global-variables

I have a header file which holds all my global variables(and a cpp file to declare them)
and I use the `#ifndef` `#define` `#endif` tags, but I still get redefinition errors

I have a total of 3 header files and 4 cpp files, and all of the header / main.cpp contains the globalvar.h header file.

Here is the code:

#### GlobalVar.h

```
#ifndef GLOBALVAR_H
#define GLOBALVAR_H
#include "SDL.h"

extern const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 960;
extern const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 960;
extern const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

extern const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 30;
//tiles attribute
extern const int TILE_WIDTH = 64;
extern const int TILE_HEIGHT = 64;
extern const int TOTAL_TILES = 150;
extern const int TOTAL_SPRITES = 64;
//tile sprites
extern SDL_Rect clip[144];
//Images / backgrounds
extern SDL_Surface* screen;
extern SDL_Surface* background;
extern SDL_Surface* Ike;
extern SDL_Surface* thetiles;
extern SDL_Event event;

#endif
```

#### GlobalVar.cpp

```
#include "GlobalVar.h"

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 960;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 960;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 30;
//tiles attribute
const int TILE_WIDTH = 64;
const int TILE_HEIGHT = 64;
const int TOTAL_TILES = 150;
const int TOTAL_SPRITES = 64;
//tile sprites
SDL_Rect clip[144];
//Images / backgrounds
SDL_Surface* screen;
SDL_Surface* background;
SDL_Surface* Ike;
SDL_Surface* thetiles;
SDL_Event event;
```

Comment: Are you providing defintions to global variables in all the source files like you did in `GlobalVar.cpp` ?

Comment: You should remove the assignments in your externs, and the clip[144] s.b. clip[] as well.  You might also place these in a namespace or static class to keep from colliding with other globals (in SDL, for instance.)  Aside from that, you'll need to provide the compiler errors, and show the usage in your other files.

Comment: It's very simple. Don't use global variables.

Answer (score 12):

You have two options for how to deal with the constants which cause the trouble.

#### Option 1

Remove the `extern` from the header:

```
#ifndef GLOBALVAR_H
#define GLOBALVAR_H
#include "SDL.h"

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 960;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 960;
const int SCREEN_BPP = 32;

const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 30;
const int TILE_WIDTH = 64;
const int TILE_HEIGHT = 64;
const int TOTAL_TILES = 150;
const int TOTAL_SPRITES = 64;

extern SDL_Rect clip[144];
extern SDL_Surface* screen;
extern SDL_Surface* background;
extern SDL_Surface* Ike;
extern SDL_Surface* thetiles;
extern SDL_Event event;

#endif
```

If you do this, you must not define the variables in `GlobalVar.cpp`.

#### Option 2

Remove the initializers from the header:

```
#ifndef GLOBALVAR_H
#define GLOBALVAR_H
#include "SDL.h"

extern const int SCREEN_WIDTH; // = 960;
extern const int SCREEN_HEIGHT; // = 960;
extern const int SCREEN_BPP; // = 32;

extern const int FRAMES_PER_SECOND; // = 30;
extern const int TILE_WIDTH; // = 64;
extern const int TILE_HEIGHT; // = 64;
extern const int TOTAL_TILES; // = 150;
extern const int TOTAL_SPRITES; // = 64;

extern SDL_Rect clip[144];
extern SDL_Surface* screen;
extern SDL_Surface* background;
extern SDL_Surface* Ike;
extern SDL_Surface* thetiles;
extern SDL_Event event;

#endif
```

Now you do need to define and initialize the constants in `GlobalVar.cpp`.

This disadvantage of this is that you cannot use names such as SCREEN_WIDTH in contexts that require a compile-time integer constant, such as the dimensions of an array or the `case` clauses of a `switch` statement.

So, option 1 is the technique which is used more often.

Answer (score 4):

You should only give the constants values in one place.

You an either keep the `extern` declarations in the header (without the values) and have the values in the cpp file, *or* remove the `extern` keyword and define the values in the header only.